# Reference/source of this theorem

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, coloring, hypergraphs

Anyone knows the specific reference of the following result? It seems like a standard result in Hypergraph Colorings, so I suspect that it may have been proven (it could be in Extremal Finite Set Theory papers too). [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eWqN.png)
Thank you.

Edit: The set theoretic formulation is as follows. Determine the partition (c_1, c_2, ..., c_\lambda) of a positive integer n such that the sum (over all i's) of {{c_i}\choose {q}} is the minimum.

Comment: That image must be from a reference. What is the question then?

Comment: I typed it out.

Comment: But where did you get the original from?

Comment: The original is a much more general and unsolved question from the textbook "Coloring mixed hypergraphs: Theory, algorithms, and applications" by Voloshin. I thought this is a easier and natural sub-problem and solved it; but I did not see it anywhere else.